# Bash: Copy n number of files for every year of birth on the filename

Tags: bash, shell-script, files

I have thousands of photos with year of birth in the filename. I need to find and copy at least 100 files for each birthyear, let's say 100 files for birthyear 2000, 100 files for 2001,..., and so on.

Here's the format of the filenames:

> 35077502_1995-02-01_2012.jpg

2012 is the year the photo is taken, i guess.

Can it be done using bash script?

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify how the files are named? Is the birthyear part of the filename? And just to make sure, you need exactly n files for each year, right?

Comment: can you give us directory listing ?

Comment: The solution provided by Philippos below already does the job but I'm still finding a tweak for it so that the search will skip corrupted files (files with 333 or 0 bytes size)

Comment: Oh, so “In the case of the sample file, 1995 is the year of birth and 2012 is the year the photo was taken.” That’s what edits are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no nasty things in the filenames you can do

```
for year in 2000 2001; do
  cp `ls *${year}*.jpg|head -n 100` destination
done
```

Comment: actually, they do include month and day. can i do `*[2000-2001]*` ?

Comment: You need the loop to take 100 pictures from each year.

Comment: Thank you for assistance Philippos. By the way, the filenames are in these format 32714_1945-01-15_2001.jpg, 2001 being the date taken. So I need the filter the 1945. Sorry for overlooking this on the original question

Comment: In this case change the pattern to `*_${year}-*jpg` to make sure you don't catch the wrong number.

Comment: Now it's working. Lastly, how can I filter files with at least KB in size? I just noticed many of the files copied are corrupted and have 333 bytes only in size. Hopefully this is not too much. Thanks again

Comment: Since you don't care which 100 pictures are taken, you can do it fairly simple: Add option `-S` to the `ls` command. This will sort the files by size, biggest file first. Thus, `head` will reduce the file list to the 100 biggest per year. If your request was solved, please take the time to mark the question as answered.

Comment: @tr3s: No, `*[2000-2001]*` won’t do what you want.  `[…]` works on a character basis, so your pattern would match any file whose name contains a `0`, `1`, or `2`.

Comment: @Philippos: (1) We prefer that, when you identify shortcomings in your answer ***and identify remedies***, you [edit] the answer to incorporate the improvements — especially after the OP has said that your suggested revision actually does result in a working solution.  Future readers (if any) shouldn’t need to read all the comments to get the complete answer.  (2) I don’t understand why the OP said that your `*_${year}-*jpg` glob works, since the question (now) shows a filename of `35077502_1995-02-01_2012.jpg` as an example of a 2012 photo  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (i.e., there is no **`-`** after the year that they want to filter on).  If that’s right, the glob has to be `*_${year}*jpg`, `*_${year}*.jpg`, or `*_${year}.jpg`. (3) The question title says “recursively”, and this script does not descend into subdirectories.  Perhaps the question title is just worded incorrectly, as the OP accepted your answer.

Comment: @G-Man: You're right that the files are contained in sub-directories but that was resolved when I did *`./*/*_${year}-*jpg|head -n 100`*. Philippos solution is correct since the task is to filter birthyears contained in filenames which is 1995 and not 2012 in the provided sample filename. Again, 2012 is the year the photo was taken.

Comment: May I redirect you to this new question: [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/384424/244949). I have created a new thread because the concept of the problem is totally different. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n' years=( $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.jpg' -print0 | 
                    sed -zEn 's/^.*_([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])-.*\.jpg/\1/p' | 
                    tr '\0' '\n' | 
                    sort -u)
                )

for year in "${years[@]}" ; do
  mkdir -p "$year"
  find . -iname "*_${year}-*.jpg" -size +1k -print0 |
    head -z -n 100 |
    xargs -0r cp -t "$year"
done
```

This constructs an array (`$years`) containing the unique set of 4-digit years extracted from filenames in the current directory, where the year is preceded by an underscore (`_`) and followed by a dash (`-`).  This requires the GNU version of `sed` for the `-z` aka `--null-data` option.

For each year, it first creates a directory for that year if one doesn't already exist, then uses `find` to list all filenames matching those required pattern that are larger than 1 KB in size.  That list is then  pipe through `head` to get only the first 100 lines, and then into `xargs` to copy the files to the appropriate directory.

The filename list is NUL-terminated throughout the entire pipeline so that it works with all valid filenames (i.e. it will not break if spaces, tabs, newlines, or other unusual but perfectly valid characters are in the filenames)

This also requires [the GNU version of `head`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/head-invocation.html) (which is standard on Linux), because it uses the `-z` option (aka `--zero-terminated`) for NUL-terminated input.  Specifically, it requires a version [more recent than 13 Jan 2016](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=commit;h=bc94551f63cfc4c05a56628dfcb386707d9e98cb).   It also requires GNU `cp` for the `-t` (aka `--target-directory`) option, which allows the target directory to be the first argument rather than the last.

If the files need to be sorted, then `sort -z` can be inserted between the `find` and `head` commands - e.g. `find ... -print0 | sort -z ... | head -z ...`.  This also requires the GNU version of `sort`.

This assumes that, as indicated in the revision to your question,
the filenames have an underscore followed by the year as the last thing before the `.jpg` extension.

If the year can appear anywhere in the filename, you may need to use `-iname "*${year}*.jpg"` (without the underscore and with a second `*` between the `${year}` and the `.jpg`) but watch out for files where the eight-digit number at the beginning is something like `60420017`, which contains `2001` as a substring.

This also assumes that all your files have (case-insensitive) `.jpg` extensions (and not `.jpeg`, `.jpe`, `.jfif`, `.gif`, `.png`, etc.).  If multiple filename extensions are required, the `-iregex` option could be used instead of `-iname`.

Comment: (1) Thanks for providing an answer that doesn’t parse the output of ```ls``` and that handles weird filenames. (2) I edited it; you are of course free to tweak further or rollback.

Comment: You have misinterpreted the info on the filenames. In the case of the sample file, 1995 is the year of birth and 2012 is the year the photo was taken. By the way, may I redirect you to this new question: [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/384424/244949). I have created a new thread because the concept of the problem is different. Thanks

Comment: @tr3s see updated version.  this one now uses the birth year, not year the photo was taken.  it also first builds a list of birth years to search for.

Comment: BTW, unless you really need copies, creating symlinks or hard links would be a lot faster and use a lot less disk space.

Comment: Agree. It's working correctly now. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
for y ({1995..2017}) (cp -- **/*_$y.jpg(.LK+1[1,100]) destination)
```

- `**/`: in any level of sub-directories, sorted alphabetically
- `.`: regular files only
- `LK+1`: more than 1KiB in length
- `[1,100]`: first hundred ones.

(as the sorting order will determine which files are copied, you may want to add the `n` glob qualifier for the sorting to be numerical).

Or to avoid hard coding the list of years and crawl the directory several times:

```sh
typeset -A files n
for f (**/*_<->.jpg(.LK+1)) {
  y=${${f##*_}%.*}
  ((++n[$y] > 100)) || files[$y]+=$f$'\0'
}
for y (${(k)files}) {
  mkdir -p $y && cp -- ${(0)files[$y]} $y
}
```

(untested)